# JaVers and Spring boot: Changed property filter for multi properties

Tags: java, spring, javers

I'm using Javers to audit changes all of the entities. Now I want to get `Changes` with `JqlQuery`, in which I only want to get the changes of the entity that has 2 changed properties: `name`, `description`. I used the method: `QueryBuilder.withChangedProperty` to filter(follow the document https://javers.org/documentation/jql-examples/#property-filter), my question is how can I use `OR` for 2 `changed properties`, something like:

```
builder.withChangedProperty("name").or(withChangedProperty("description"))
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: duplicate to https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/919

Comment: @BartekWalacik Okay, let's move to Github issues. Thank you.